# Python: Is there a way a swipl query results in value true not {}?

Tags: python, prolog, boolean, rules

To call prolog programs in python there is the libary pyswip.

Is there a possibility to get information if a rule for a given value is true or false. If I call a fact in console from swipl I get e.g.

> ```
> ?- dad(a).
> true.
> ```

If I try the same in python with:

from pyswip import Prolog, registerForeign

```
from pyswip import Prolog
prolog = Prolog()

prolog.assertz("dad(peter)")

for res in prolog.query("dad(peter)."):
    print(res)
```

It gives me only the output:

> {}

and not True. Is there another function I can call to get True or False at this point or is the expected value of the query function in that case {}?

Comment: For SWI-Prolog to Python you should take a look at [SWI Prolog Machine Query Interface and Python Integration](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-mqi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Prolog's point of view, `{}` is the expected result. When a Prolog query succeeds, Prolog prints a set of answer substitutions:

```
?- dad(X).
X = peter.
```

*As a special case*, if no variables from the query are bound, Prolog needs to indicate that (a) the query succeeded, and that (b) no variables were bound. Traditionally, this is done by printing something like `yes` or `true`. But this is just a shorthand for "success, and there were zero substitutions". And it's only a *printing* convention, not a "return value" in any real sense. Prolog has no return values.

If you use a foreign library that represents success-and-a-set-of-answer-substitutions using the language's set type, then it makes sense that success-and-zero-substitutions is represented as a zero-element set, i.e., `{}`.